# The practical effect issue of 'constant' in SceneKit's lighting model

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnmaterial, sceneeditor

I'm learning about SceneKit's lighting model, and I noticed in Apple's official documentation that the explanation for 'constant' is:

[image]

This means that 'constant' should consider both ambient light and diffuse light.

However, when I placed an ambient light with a yellow color in the Scene Editor, I found that the 'constant' model doesn't seem to consider ambient light. On the other hand, the PBR and Blinn models correctly reflect the yellow ambient light. I'm curious to know why this is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This issustration seems to come from the SceneGraph Editor in XCode. What happens if you Build and Run the App?

Comment: @ZAY The actual effect of the app during runtime is the same as in the Scene Editor. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

Comment: can you post the code, how you setup all your lights?

Comment: @ZAY I simply dragged three spheres and an Ambient Light in the Scene Editor without writing any additional code.